# Creating a standalone gtkmm dialog

Tags: c++, dialog, gtkmm

In a particular situation I need my command line based C++ application to launch a quick dialog using gtkmm 2.4. I could really use some direction here.

I tried launching the dialog as a standalone without initializing the top level window:

```
Gtk::Main kit( NULL,NULL );
Gtk::Window toplevel;
MyApp::myDialog d(toplevel);
int result = d.run();
```

This created my dialog but it doesn't close when the ok or cancel button is hit and none of quit/delete/hide api calls I could find could get rid of it. It only goes away when the program exits (even if it is created in a method which exits earlier). I'm guessing this is in part because it needs an active main window to handle some of its lifetime/visibility management. If I could make it respond normally to the ok/cancel buttons I would be all set!

Next I tried creating and launching the main window properly and launching the dialog from within the constructor of the main window. (It takes the Gtk::Main as an argument so I could try killing that directly.)

```
class cprompt : public Gtk::Window
{
  public:    
    cprompt(Gtk::Main* prompt){
    MyApp::myDialog* d = new MyApp::myDialog (*this);
    std::cout << "ABOUT TO RUN DIALOG" << std::endl;
    int result = d->run();
    std::cout << "RAN DIALOG" << std::endl;
    d->hide();
    delete d;

    std::cout << "CALLING QUIT" << std::endl;
    this->hide();
    Gtk::Main::quit();
    prompt->quit();
    //None of the above calls do anything. The empty 'top level' window hangs around and blocks until manually closed.
    std::cout << "CALLED QUIT" << std::endl;
    };
    virtual                 ~cprompt(){};
};
```

Now the dialog works as expected, but the main window pops up after the dialog is closed (an empty gray square with an exit button) and I can't find a way to hide or exit it outside of clicking the exit button. All the calls I make to close it or quit the gtk loop automatically are inside the constructor so I'm guessing they aren't valid at that point. If I could make the whole operation shut down after the dialog returns in the window constructor, again I would be all set.

My next approach is going to be to use the top level window itself as the dialog, but I was hoping to avoid this because the dialog I need is already provided by another library and I'll have to re-implement the ui from scratch if I can't launch the dialog straight up.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Gtk. To fix it, I neeeded to manually close the window and then do the gtk loop iterations. My code looks like this (for a filechooser_dialog) :

```
gint result = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(m_fileDialog));

if(result == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
{
    char* filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(m_fileDialog));
    m_selectedFileName = std::string(filename);

    g_free(filename);
}

gtk_window_close(GTK_WINDOW(m_fileDialog)); //Close the dialog manually

while (gtk_events_pending()) //until there are no more events :
    gtk_main_iteration_do(false); //process the main iteration
```